# How to use dplyr filter to select observations satisfying two conditions from another data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame looks like

```
state    year  taxrev
Alabama  1970  209297
Alabama  1971  239502
...
Alabama  1981  239502
Alaska   1970  209701
Alaska   1971  230980
...
Alaska   1981  230982
...
```

I also have a reference data frame like this

```
state   year 
Alabama  1975
Alaska   1977
Illinois 1973
...
```

How do I get the taxrev for the state-year pairs in the reference data frame using dplyr (I know how to do it with base R)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to filter. Use `match_df` function of `plyr` package.

See this example

**Data**

```
my_data <- data.frame(state=c(rep("Alabama",3),rep("Alaska",3)),year=c(1970,1971,1975,1977,1963,1975),taxrev=c(209297,239502,254663,209701,230982,26789))
ref_data <- data.frame(state=c("Alabama","Alaska"),year=c(1975,1977))
```

**R Code**

```
match_df(my_data,ref_data)
```

**Output**

```
    state year taxrev
3 Alabama 1975 254663
4  Alaska 1977 209701
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are consistently named as in your example and your 2 data frames are called taxrev_df and reference_df respectively then:

`reference_df <- left_join(reference_df, taxrev_df)`

Comment: I'd give the resultant dataframe a new name and not use `reference_df` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Also this would probably work, though untested because of no reproducible data:

```
reference_df %>%
 filter(year %in% taxrev_df$year)
```